# element not interactable isssue when clicking the button

Tags: katalon-studio

[image]

[![When I tried to run this test caseAnd clicked the Employee button its shows that Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
At object: 'Object Repository/Login_Employee/Page_/a_Employees'

[image]

Im tried add waitfor lines but still it could not see the button i clicked.

Comment: You are verifying that `Login_Employee/Page_/a_Employees` is clickable and then trying to click `Object Repository/Login_Employee/Page_/a_Employees`. Can you share how are they defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved already, I just used the Enhanced Click since when I checked there were so many overlays which I think it blocks the "normal click".